# Import error: No module named 'glob'

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all, I got an import error from executing `roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_no_controllers.launch`:

```
ros@ros-K401UB:~/research/gps$ roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_no_controllers.launch 
... logging to /home/ros/.ros/log/751a586e-bd85-11e7-a646-9c5c8ed99f00/roslaunch-ros-K401UB-4556.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 60, in <module>
    import xacro
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import glob
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'glob'

while processing /opt/ros/indigo/share/pr2_description/robots/upload_pr2.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py '/opt/ros/indigo/share/pr2_description/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find pr2_description)/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro'" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

However, I can import glob in python2.7:

```
ros@ros-K401UB:~/research/gps$ python2.7
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import glob
>>>
```

Also, I can locate it under `/usr/lib/python2.7`:

```
ros@ros-K401UB:/usr/lib/python2.7$ ls | grep glo
glob.py
glob.pyc
```

Thus, I guess that the problem occurs because the python executable which runs xacro.py can't locate the module glob in its path. So I tried to append /usr/lib/python2.7 to my PYTHONPATH, but this doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks for any suggestion : )

P.S. I am using Ubuntu 14.04+ROS Indigo, and my `python -m site` output this:

```
ros@ros-K401UB:~/research/gps$ python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/ros/research/gps',
    '/home/ros/research/tool/rllab',
    '/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/home/ros/miniconda3/lib/python36.zip',
    '/home/ros/miniconda3/lib/python3.6',
    '/home/ros/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
    '/home/ros/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
    '/home/ros/code/gym',
    '/home/ros/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/ros/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/ros/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Reference:

1. http://forum.erlerobotics.com/t/solved-error-with-no-module-named-glob/829
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964691/how-to-install-the-glob-module

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274571/import-error:-no-module-named-%27glob%27/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-10-30**:
Seems to me like you have more than one Python version. Why did you specifically type `python2.7` when testing for glob and then `python` in other tests? Are you sure they are the same Python? Can you try disabling conda and then running your launch file?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-10-30**:
What do `which python` and `which python2.7` return?

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-10-30**:
I think ROS does not support Python 3, so you might want to start from there.
Also, I've had many issues while trying to use Miniconda/Anaconda with ROS, so when I need to use ROS I just comment it out from my `.bashrc`

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2017-10-30**:
Thanks to both of you jarvisschultz & bpinaya!!! The problem is caused by miniconda, I'll leave the result in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the advice from [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) & [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/), I removed the miniconda/anaconda part in `~/.basrc`:

```
# added by Miniconda3 4.3.21 installer
#export PATH="/home/ros/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

And after that, I can successfully `roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_no_controllers.launch`, and the output of `python -m site` became:

```
sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Box2D-2.3.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
    '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/ros/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/ros/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

This problem is solved.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0